# Show $A^k$ doesn't converge to $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, jordan-normal-form, spectral-radius

Let $A \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}$. Let $r=\{\max \lvert \lambda \rvert \text{ such that }\lambda \in \mathbb C \text { is an eigenvalue of } A\}$. If $r\geq 1$ show that $A^k$ doesn't converge to the zero matrix as $k\to \infty$.

Here is the proof I wrote :

$A=P^{-1}JP$ with $P$ inversible and $J$ in a Jordan normal form. Let $\lambda_m$ be the eigenvalue that has $\lvert \lambda_m \rvert=r\geq 1$.
We have that $A^k=P^{-1}J^kP$. Then I show by induction that $J^k$ has a coefficient $A_{ij}=a\lambda_m^k+b$ where $a, b\in \mathbb C^{n}$ (they do not matter). Now since that $\lvert \lambda_m \rvert \geq 1$ then $A_{ij}$ diverges when $n$ goes to $+\infty$ that means that $A^k$ does not converge to the zero matrix.

Is it correct ?

Comment: Seems like overkill to me.  Why not just notice that $A^kv = \lambda^k v\not\rightarrow 0$ for $v$ eigenvector with eigenvalue $|\lambda| \geq 1$?

Comment: @JairTaylor I didn't think of it, but is my proof correct or is there something wrong with it ?

Comment: I think the idea works. I'm not sure about the formula you have for $A_{ij}$, though. I think it should be a function of the other eigenvalues as well.

Comment: If you use Schur's Inequality you have   

$\big \Vert A^k\big \Vert_F^2 \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \vert \lambda^k\vert^2\geq  r^2  \geq 1$  
for all k  $\implies A\not \to \mathbf 0$

Answer (score 3):

This is almost correct. You don’t need to use the normal form. You have an eigenvector $v_m$, so $A^k v_m = \lambda^k_m v_m$. In particular, there’s no problem with multiplication of Jordan matrices. This is the weakest spot in your proof.

Comment: I wrote this proof in an exam and wanted to know if what I did is correct.

Comment: Can you please explain what is wrong ?

Comment: @John $a$ and $b$ do matter, actually, so this is a weak spot.

Comment: @John $a$ and $b$ can depend on the power, so you have to prove, that $a_k\lambda^k_m + b_k$ doesn’t go to zero.